# php upload image change name to id number in database

Tags: php, html, css

Im trying to make my image upload for user avatars to have the name of the id of their profile in the database been trying for days not getting anywhere

I have tried the following and none of them are working. i can pull the id of the user on that page with  but its not working like so.

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "instructors/$id.jpg")) {

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "instructors/"$id".jpg")) {

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "instructors/".$id.".jpg")) {

Heres Full Code

```html
<?php

}


// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{
 

// confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data

if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))

{

// get form data, making sure it is valid

$id = $_POST['id'];

$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']));

$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']));



// check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in

if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '')

{

// generate error message

$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';



//error, display form

renderForm($id, $firstname, $lastname, $error);

}

else

{

// save the data to the database

mysql_query("UPDATE instructors SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname' WHERE id='$id'")

or die(mysql_error());



// once saved, redirect back to the view page



}

}

else

{

// if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error

echo 'Error!';

}

}
$target_dir = "instructors/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {

        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {

        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "instructors/$id.jpg")) {

    } else {

    }
}  


// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)

{

// query db

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM instructors WHERE id=$id")

or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);



// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse

if($row)

{



// get data from db

$firstname = $row['firstname'];

$lastname = $row['lastname'];



// show form

renderForm($id, $firstname, $lastname, '');

}

else

// if no match, display result

{

echo "No results!";

}

}

else

// if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error

{

echo 'Error!';

}


?>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the error_log? The destination path looks wrong to me, shouldn't it be prefixed with an actual path instead of being relative?

Comment: The main thing to ask is - does the file even save?

Comment: `I have tried the following and none of them are working` - we can assume it doesn't. And if it does, it's probably saving into a directory outside of where the op things it should be.

Comment: JCode yes the file saves but just has extension jpg no name